# How to make an element match the height of a dynamic page

Tags: html, css

In my CSS I have a navigation bar on the side and a container which shows the content of the page. I have php spit out a big table of data and I want the navigation bar to extend all the way down to the bottom of the page to match the table height.

How do I do this? I've got the following code but the nav bar doesn't match the height of the page when it's a long page (it stops very short at just the size of a normal page).

```css
#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #F9F9F9
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
  /*top right bottom left*/
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  content
</div>

<div id="navigation">
  navbar
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Rather than having a height of 100% you should give the #navigation a top of 0 and bottom of 0

Comment: That still doesn't work, it starts the navbar from the bottom of a normal sized page... but the content has stretched the page to about 100 pages long downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make sure your nav bar is inside the container. Set the container to position relative and apply top, bottom, and left positioning to the nav.

Here is an example... http://jsbin.com/ramoj/1/edit

```
#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

}

#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding-left: 250px;
  background-color: green;
}

<div id="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet similique aspernatur consequuntur consequatur optio totam tenetur unde quo consectetur pariatur laborum officia numquam illum incidunt molestiae debitis possimus quis cupiditate!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet similique aspernatur consequuntur consequatur optio totam tenetur unde quo consectetur pariatur laborum officia numquam illum incidunt molestiae debitis possimus quis cupiditate!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet similique aspernatur consequuntur consequatur optio totam tenetur unde quo consectetur pariatur laborum officia numquam illum incidunt molestiae debitis possimus quis cupiditate!
  <div id="navigation">
    navbar
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `table-cell` for the divs instead of `position:absolute` you can expand the div.  Here's a js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6j2u3oz/1/

I would take out the margins and all that and use an encompassing div to make those kind of changes where it sits on the body also, that way controlling the expanding div height is clean.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving the #navigation div inside the #container div, and in your CSS changing the position property of #container to "relative".

You'll have to play around with the positioning of the navbar a bit, but with these settings the element should now expand to the height of your table now.

http://jsfiddle.net/ben220/ovh14pm0/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="navigation">
navbar
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt       
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -210px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /*margin-top: 100px;*/
  background-color: blue;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
  /*top right bottom left*/
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  background-color: green;
}
```